# Julia - Constraint Programming in JuMP

Tags: julia, cplex, constraint-programming, julia-jump

I know we can use CPLEX in Julia JuMP, for linear programming for instance.
But can we use CPLEX in JuMP, Julia v1.1 for constraint programming ?

[CPLEX and OPL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/OPL_Studio/oplmigration/topics/opl_mig_reln_52_supp.html) can do constraint programming, but what about Julia, are there documentation pages in JuMP linked to that or is it planned to be developped in near future for Julia ?

Comment: Mathematical optimization and Constraint Programming are very very different branches and seeing all the software already developed around JuMP and also the research area of the people behind it (MathOpt), i would guess CP will never be a part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation at http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.18/installation.html#getting-solvers JUMP CPLEX support includes:

- Linear programming
- Second-order conic programming (including problems with convex quadratic constraints and/or objective)
- Mixed-integer linear programming

Comment: Will constraint programming be implemented in JuMP in near future ?

Comment: This looks like a good idea to raise issue at JuMP  Github. I see two options: (1) try `IntervalConstraintProgramming.jl` and (2) for some problem settings you could try to use JuMP Lazy Constraints to iterate over the feasible set - they are nicely described in docs and should work with CPLEX (note to others - currently lazy constraints with the GLPK solver are buggy).

Comment: For everyone interested in it now: There is https://github.com/dourouc05/JuCP.jl 
and I currently build a solver from scratch: https://github.com/Wikunia/ConstraintSolver.jl For the latter you probably have to wait a couple of years for it to be useful ;)